# Authenticating a dockerized Spring Boot app against a dockerized & linked ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I'm starting my activemq container like so:

```
docker run -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 --name='activemq' -d \
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG' \
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_USER=bot' \
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD=blahblah' \
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_OWNER_LOGIN=bot' \
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_OWNER_PASSWORD=blahblah' \
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_JMX_LOGIN=bot' \
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_JMX_PASSWORD=blahblah' \
-v /data/activemq:/data/activemq \
-v /var/log/activemq:/var/log/activemq \
webcenter/activemq:latest
```

The application.yml for my app has the following:

```
spring:
  activemq:
    broker-url: ${ACTIVEMQ_PORT_61616_TCP}
    user: bot
    password: blahblah
```

and I'm starting my app container like so:

```
docker run --name='myapp' \
-w /app/ -v /home/ubuntu/myapp/logs:/app/logs \
-v /home/ubuntu/myapp/config:/app/config \
-v /tmp:/tmp -p 4980:4980 \
--link activemq:activemq \
-d myapp
```

Note that I'm linking my app's container with the activemq container.

Finally, when I attempt to send a msg to activeMQ from my app (via a Camel route - but I don't think that's relevant), I see this in the logs:

```
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User name [bot] or password is invalid.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1417)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1522)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:527)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:400)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:907)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:882)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1053)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: User name [bot] or password is invalid.
    at org.apache.activemq.security.JaasAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(JaasAuthenticationBroker.java:80)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConnection(MutableBrokerFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:764)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:294)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:148)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for activemq-domain
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:264)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:417)
    at org.apache.activemq.security.JaasAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(JaasAuthenticationBroker.java:72)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Needless to say, it all 'just works' when running these components locally (i.e. not dockerized) on my dev machine. Just doesn't work inside docker containers on an EC2 instance.

Any and all help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Does your spring app load the environment variables?

Comment: @Michael Yes it does. I can see some other stuff in the logs which can only have come from the yml file. Also, I was previously getting a connection exception before I introduced the env. variable for spring.activemq.broker-url. And now i'm getting this auth exception. That suggests that it is now connecting - and it can only be doing so as a result of having read the yml file.

Answer (score 2):

I have eventually got it to work by customising the docker image as follows:

1. Clone the git repo: `git clone https://github.com/disaster37/activemq.git`
2. Fix the URL passed to curl in this file: `assets/setup/install`
   (the current url in that file no longer works)
3. Edit this file: `assets/config/activemq.xml` and replace the `<jaasAuthenticationPlugin>` and `<authorizationPlugin>` elements with this:

`<simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="false">
    <users>
        <authenticationUser username="system" password="blubblub" groups="users,admins"/>
       <authenticationUser username="bot" password="blahblah" groups="users"/>
    </users>
 </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>`

4. Build my own docker image: `docker build --tag="zackattack/activemq"`
5. Run it: `docker logs -f $(docker run --name='activemq' -d zackattack/activemq)`

It's not pretty - but it works!

Comment: I dont see assets/config/activemq.xml in this repo. Should i create it?

Comment: Looks like the maintainer of that repo has deleted it.
You can still find it though in his 5.10.0 tag here: `https://github.com/disaster37/activemq/tree/5.10.0`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what I can glean from the debug logs.  First, the debug log shows that 'bot' is getting across (the name), so, there does appear to be a connection between myapp and activemq. So the linkage is working.  The clue for me is :

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for activemq-domain
```

I don't know what a login module is, but, I would venture a guess that you need to tell activemq what to do with the name/password it receives?  Looking at the description on the docker hub for activemq, there is an example:

```
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_READ_LOGIN=consumer_login' -e 'ACTIVEMQ_READ_PASSWORD=consumer_password'\
```

and

```
-e 'ACTIVEMQ_STATIC_TOPICS=topic1;topic2;topic3' -e 'ACTIVEMQ_STATIC_QUEUES=queue1;queue2;queue3'
```

Is it possible that either of these settings is needed to configure an activemq-domain login module?  Or is that done in a configuration file somewhere?  From a docker perspective I think everything is in order. I think there is a configuration issue with activemq.  When this works in your regular environment, how do you start activemq (what are the command line arguments, environment variables, and configuration files)?

Comment: Thanks for weighing in there Greg. As far as I can see, the LoginModule should be correctly set up as a result of the jaasAuthenticationPlugin specified in this file: https://github.com/disaster37/activemq/blob/master/assets/config/activemq.xml - since I have tried passing all suggested username/pwd parameters into the process when I run it